# Cassandra SSTable corruption - How to prevent?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

We running a two data center Cassandra cluster. And write data from Apache spark using Cassandra spark connector.

We sometimes see SS Table corruption errors in some nodes.
Below is a sample exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: Corrupted: /cassandra/data/data/ams/mydata_attr_v1-de4f9960a01711e783ea2bd3a6beadcf/mc-2925-big-Data.db at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2490) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_72] at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~

My questions:

1. What are the reason for SSTable corruption errors?
2. How do I prevent SSTable corruption errors?

I see documentation on how fix SStable errors when it happens, but there is no clear documentation on causes of these errors and preventing them.

Answer (score 0):

Sstable corruption can occur due to

1. Abrupt shutdown of Cassandra node due to power failure or manual shutdown
2. Disk failure.

Always try to shutdown Cassandra gracefully by running `nodetool drain` before stopping Cassandra manually.

Comment: 1  didn't happen. There was no abrupt power failure or manual shutdown.   Is there any logs to check and make sure it is due to disk failure. SSTable error sometime recovers. And I see SSTable errors in single keyspace even though there are other keyspaces which are working fine.

Comment: Are there any other causes?  like network issue? Can we detect these from logs what was the actual root cause of the SSTable issue?

Comment: "Maximum memory usage reached (512.000MiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB" Getting these logs a lot, can this cause sstable corruption?

Comment: I also see a lot of these errors in all nodes "FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time "

Comment: I would recommend getting your disk checked. I dont think network issue could cause sstable corruption. Try to identify the cause, is it occuring in one keyspace  all the time in different hardwares or only one set of hardware is causing the issue.